# Rails - How to make use of Active Storage JavaScript events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am working with [Active Storage](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activestorage#direct-upload-javascript-events) of RubyonRails, it seems that when a form is submitted certain JavaScript events are executed (at least this is what my understanding is) and I am trying to listen to these events.

My form is pretty simple just an input field and image field

```
<%= form_with(model: to_do, local: true, id: 'image_form') do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, id: :to_do_title %>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :image %>
     <%= form.file_field :image, direct_upload: true %><br>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit id: 'submit_button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Inside `application.js` file I added the following code to test what happens but unfortunately none of my tries work

```
addEventListener("direct-upload:initialize", doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e) {
    alert("Event is called: " + e.type);
}

document.getElementById("image_form").addEventListener("direct-upload:initialize", function() {
  console.log('direct-uploads:initialize')
});

document.getElementById("image_form").addEventListener("direct-uploads:end", function() {
  console.log('direct-uploads:start')
});
```

When I submit the form although the data gets saved in database but my event listener does not listen to the event as i do not get any alert.

So my question is

**How to listen to these [Active Storage](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activestorage#direct-upload-javascript-events) javascript events when a form is submitted?**

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the form submission is happening too quickly, and therefore you can't see any of the event listener's output.

Start with adding this to your view with your form:

```
<%= form_with(model: to_do, local: true, id: 'image_form') do |form| %>
  ... form stuff ...
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(document.querySelector('#image_form')); // Log the form, for debugging      
  document.querySelector('#image_form').addEventListener('direct-uploads:start', function() {
    console.log('Event was called');
  });
</script>
```

Additionally, you may want to preserve your web browser's console log prior to submitting the form, so you'd see the log message.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for having a look but unfortunately this does not work either

Comment: You added the javascript to the view, instead of your application.js? Your JS likely isn't working when added to the application.js as the DOM probably isn't loaded (assuming it's included in the `head` of your document).

Comment: Yes I added this inside a view and removed it form the application.js file

Comment: Are you sure your file is uploading directly to your cloud provider, and not just uploading inside the form?

Comment: yes files are being uploaded in a bucket of aws i have confirmed that, however i am not sure what do you mean by your second statement "not just uploading inside a form?"

Comment: The direct upload JS is for uploading the file directly from your browser directly to the bucket. Non-direct uploads (as part of the form submission) would go from your browser to your rails server to your bucket. Make sure the network requests are being made from your browser directly to your bucket, otherwise these events will never be emitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157930/discussion-between-baig-and-daniel-westendorf).

Comment: From reading your last comment this is what i understood that these events will fire only when I am uploading the file to the bucket via js directly (if yes how to do that?) before submitting the form? But if i upload this image on submitting the form these events will not fire. Did you understand you right? If yes then can you refer me to the documentation where you read this?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to events on the input field itself.
So in your case it will be

```
"#{model_name}_#{attachment_name}" which is to_do_image


document.getElementById("to_do_image").addEventListener("direct-upload:initialize",
function() {
  console.log('direct-uploads:initialize')
});

document.getElementById("image_form").addEventListener("direct-uploads:end", function() {
  console.log('direct-uploads:start')
});
```